# is there an R function to filter any string in a variable?

Tags: r, string, filter, dplyr, character

I have a data that has both strings and NA. I want an r function that filters any string and any NA.
My data looks like this

```
a<-c(1,2,3,4)
b<-c("james","NA",1,2)
c<-data.frame(a,b)
c
```

I need the output that looks like this

```
a<-c(1,2)
b<-c("james","NA")
d<-data.frame(a,b)
d
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select rows which do not have all the numbers.

```
subset(c, !grepl('^\\d+$', b))

#  a     b
#1 1 james
#2 2    NA
```

This can also be used in `dplyr::filter` -

```
dplyr::filter(c, !grepl('^\\d+$', b))
```

Note that in the data, you have string `"NA"` and not real `NA` value. However, above answer would also work if you had real `NA` value i.e if the `b` vector was `b<-c("james",NA,1,2)`.

Answer (score 0):

We may use `grep` with `negate = TRUE`

```
c[grep('^\\d+$', c$b, negate = TRUE),]
```

Or with `str_detect`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
c %>% 
    filter(str_detect(b, '^\\d+$', negate = TRUE))
  a     b
1 1 james
2 2    NA
```